# Printing a custom message in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have an sql command in Posgresql:

```
insert into table1(a, b, c)
select (d, e, f) from table2;
```

It's just a single command, not a procedure. 
Is there any way to print out some information to stdout after an operation on each row has been performed?
If there're 10 records in table1, there should be 10 **custom** messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this method will help you. This will return your custom message.

```
INSERT into table1(col_a1, col_a2, col_a3)
SELECT (col_b1, col_b2, col_b3) FROM table2 RETURNING 'My Message ' || col_b1 || ' ' || col_b2;
```

Comment: If you want to print the col_b1 value with your message you can use it.

Comment: If you dont want to print any column values then remove `|| col_b1`

Comment: and if I wanted to add the values of col_b1, col_a1, etc to the message, how would I do that?

Comment: `col_b1` and `col_a1` values are always same. Check the updated answer. It will retrun the values in other columns.

Answer (score 2):

> I have an sql command in Posgresql

In general, two machines (probably running Linux) and two processes are then involved, since [PostGreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/about/) has a client-server design. The RDBMS is running on one machine (in one or several processes) and listen for socket connections and handle requests on them, so each SQL command has its own request. The [client](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/client-interfaces.html) is running on some other machine (in general; in some cases it might be the *same* computer) and is using the `libpq` library or some wrapper above that. Client and server communicate using TCP/IP sockets on e.g. some Ethernet cable.

> Is there any way to print out some information to stdout after an operation

But **which *stdout*?** On the (PostGreSQL) server machine or the client one?

<sup>(server and client above are meant in the PostGreSQL sense; if you are coding a web application, e.g. in PHP - or in Ocaml with [Ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) -, it probably acts both as an HTTP server and as a PostGreSQL client)</sup>

If you want to print a custom message on the client one, you should modify the SQL command to get a list of answers (so your SQL command is likely to be some complex `SELECT`). Then you can add a `printf` after each row that you recieved from the server. Read the chapter on *[asynchronous command processing](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/libpq-async.html)* (in documentation of `libpq` *client library*) which explains how to get each row one by one and process it.

If you want to print a custom message on the *server* machine, be aware that the *stdout* of the server might be redirected to `/dev/null`. In that case, consider some [*server programming interface*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/spi.html) or some [SQL extensions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/extend.html).

Once you have understood on which side ([client or server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model), **w.r.t. PostGreSQL**) you want the *stdout* message to happen, you could program it appropriately.

Comment: on a server machine.

Comment: `might be redirected ` or might not.

Comment: Then you are contradictory. You choose the other reply as the definitive answer (and that is ok), but it is giving the message on the client machine, not "on the server machine" as your first comment is saying.

Comment: @Jodoomi : you look extremely confused: a PHP application is running on a web server (and is on the HTTP server side), but is often a PostGreSQL client application. Server & client is related to a given protocol. The same PHP program can be both an HTTP server, and a PostGreSQL client.